# Error coming while debugging my typescript file:-> Debugger attached. Waiting for the debugger to disconnect

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have gone through plethora of articles online ,I have tried every possible way given online for this but nothing has worked for me till now.
I have reinstalled node,vs code,npm all again but nothing is working.
I am using ->
VSCode Version: 1.27.2
OS Version: Windows 10 Pro 64bit OS,x64-based processor
Node version: v8.11.3 
My launch.json is as follows:-

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/dist/LeonardoGrader.js",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "runtimeArgs": [
            "--nolazy"
            ],
            "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*.js"]
            }
    ]
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That output means that your program ran to completion without ever stopping in the debugger.  Either set some breakpoints or change the `stopOnEntry` option to `true` to stop the program on the first line of code.

Comment: ,I have set many breakpoints and also tried stopOnEntry option making true but that also does not hit my breakpoint.

Comment: Then I don't know what the problem is.  I set up a project based on the information you provided, and the program stopped correctly when I set `stopOnEntry` to true.  We need to figure out what is different about your project or environment.  If you make a new TypeScript project with no code except a `console.log` and with a launch configuration with `stopOnEntry` set to true, does the same problem occur?

Comment: Yes,when i tried making another .js file and tried debugging it ,the debugger correctly stops on my breakpoint but when i try to debug my transpiled ts file ie js file in my dist folder ,the debugger just doesn't get stop on my breakpoints.

Comment: I'm glad you have a working project.  You're going to have to do some experiments to figure out what is different about the other project that causes it not to work.  For example, if you copy the entire content of the transpiled js file into the js file that is currently working, can you still debug?  If you run `node --inspect-brk dist\LeonardoGrader.js` at the command line and then run Google Chrome and go to the URL `about:inspect`, does debugging that way work?